# adhoc distribution with time limits

Tags: iphone, distribution, adhoc

Is it possible to distribute an app via adhoc or inhouse distribution that will only run for a limited period?  The provisioning profiles do not seem to allow a cut off date to be set.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You would have to implement time limiting in your application.